# Picasso library how to use transformation on placeholder/error

Tags: java, android, image, picasso, blur

**This is the code i use to display an image with picasso**

My problem is that when an album art can't be loaded,  i use placeholder or error in picasso, but both don't use the transform option to also blur the image.
The image is only blurred when an album art is found.

```
private void loadAlbumArt(){

    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, songList.get(songIndex).getAlbumID());

    int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7 };

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(myImageList.length);


    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(albumArtUri)
            .placeholder(myImageList[randomNumber])
            .transform(new BlurTransformation(getApplicationContext()))
            .noFade()
            .into(mAlbumArtLarge);

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(albumArtUri)
            .placeholder(myImageList[randomNumber])
            .into(mAlbumArt);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso does not allow placeholder and error resource transformations. See the answers [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/337).